# Define Class over 'a' Syntax

Tags: javascript

I caught a flaw in this script I'm using; It's calling the global 'a' tag - which is killing me.

What it the proper way to define a specific classes link within the 'a' tag within the snippet below?

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('.mainnav');
```

Clearly that didn't work; either did `.mainnav a`

**Full snippet:**

```
var ss = {
  fixAllLinks: function() {
    // Get a list of all links in the page
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('.mainnav');
    // Walk through the list
    for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
      var lnk = allLinks[i];
      if ((lnk.href && lnk.href.indexOf('#') != -1) && 
          ( (lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ||
        ('/'+lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ) && 
          (lnk.search == location.search)) {
        // If the link is internal to the page (begins in #)
        // then attach the smoothScroll function as an onclick
        // event handler
        ss.addEvent(lnk,'click',ss.smoothScroll);
      }
    }
  },
```

**Update:** After swapping out different tags; and trying to call with classes the script stopped functioning. Here's the full plugin; http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/smoothscroll/ I just want to use this with specific classes as opposed to all 'a' tags.

Suggestions; thanks.

Comment: Why do you use the "jquery" tag if you're clearly not using it?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is for getting elements by tag name (such as "a", "ul", etc.). If you don't care about IE8 and below, you can use `.getElementsByClassName`, or, since you tagged your question with "jquery", I'm assuming you're using it, so just do `$('.mainnav')`

Comment: Yeah sorry Blaze - was open to a jQuery solution.

Comment: Consider `querySelectorAll` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.mainnav` isn't a tag, so `getElementsByTagName` won't work. Perhaps you're looking for:

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('mainnav');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

or in jQuery:

```
$('.mainnav');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Blaze, this appears to be the answer. But replacing that line my script dies; perhaps a more detailed question of my problem could be seen here 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923063/solution-to-using-my-tag-based-smooth-scroll-script-without-a' -- Why wouldn't replacing what you suggest work with my script?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have `jquery` in your tags.  You really should use jQuery, which makes this far easier to do.  Searching for all `a` tags in the `.mainnav` is as easy as: `$(".mainnav a");`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` gets elements by their tag, not their class. Correct syntax would be `document.getElementsByTagName('a');`, and would get all `a` anchor tags. I think if you want to get all tags that have the class `mainnav`, then you need to use jQuery:

```
 $('.mainnav');
```

or

```
 var allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('mainnav');
```