# Solution to Using my Tag based Smooth Scroll Script without 'a'

Tags: javascript

OK. So, I'm wrapping up a development. I've implemented a smooth scroll script based on the 'a' tag. I don't have time to work another script, so I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to use mine, but replace the 'a' tag with something that could allow me to use this effect based only on the menu. I've tried replacing with get class and the functionality seemed to die, but maybe I implemented it wrong.

**Below is the JavaScript I'm using:**

```
/* Smooth scrolling
   Changes links that link to other parts of this page to scroll
   smoothly to those links rather than jump to them directly, which
   can be a little disorienting.

   sil, http://www.kryogenix.org/

   v1.0 2003-11-11
   v1.1 2005-06-16 wrap it up in an object
*/

var ss = {
  fixAllLinks: function() {
    // Get a list of all links in the page
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // Walk through the list
    for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
      var lnk = allLinks[i];
      if ((lnk.href && lnk.href.indexOf('#') != -1) && 
          ( (lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ||
        ('/'+lnk.pathname == location.pathname) ) && 
          (lnk.search == location.search)) {
        // If the link is internal to the page (begins in #)
        // then attach the smoothScroll function as an onclick
        // event handler
        ss.addEvent(lnk,'click',ss.smoothScroll);
      }
    }
  },

  smoothScroll: function(e) {
    // This is an event handler; get the clicked on element,
    // in a cross-browser fashion
    if (window.event) {
      target = window.event.srcElement;
    } else if (e) {
      target = e.target;
    } else return;

    // Make sure that the target is an element, not a text node
    // within an element
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a') {
      target = target.parentNode;
    }

    // Paranoia; check this is an A tag
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a') return;

    // Find the <a name> tag corresponding to this href
    // First strip off the hash (first character)
    anchor = target.hash.substr(1);
    // Now loop all A tags until we find one with that name
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var destinationLink = null;
    for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
      var lnk = allLinks[i];
      if (lnk.name && (lnk.name == anchor)) {
        destinationLink = lnk;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!destinationLink) destinationLink = document.getElementById(anchor);

    // If we didn't find a destination, give up and let the browser do
    // its thing
    if (!destinationLink) return true;

    // Find the destination's position
    var destx = destinationLink.offsetLeft; 
    var desty = destinationLink.offsetTop;
    var thisNode = destinationLink;
    while (thisNode.offsetParent && 
          (thisNode.offsetParent != document.body)) {
      thisNode = thisNode.offsetParent;
      destx += thisNode.offsetLeft;
      desty += thisNode.offsetTop;
    }

    // Stop any current scrolling
    clearInterval(ss.INTERVAL);

    cypos = ss.getCurrentYPos();

    ss_stepsize = parseInt((desty-cypos)/ss.STEPS);
    ss.INTERVAL =
setInterval('ss.scrollWindow('+ss_stepsize+','+desty+',"'+anchor+'")',10);

    // And stop the actual click happening
    if (window.event) {
      window.event.cancelBubble = true;
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
    if (e && e.preventDefault && e.stopPropagation) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  },

  scrollWindow: function(scramount,dest,anchor) {
    wascypos = ss.getCurrentYPos();
    isAbove = (wascypos < dest);
    window.scrollTo(0,wascypos + scramount);
    iscypos = ss.getCurrentYPos();
    isAboveNow = (iscypos < dest);
    if ((isAbove != isAboveNow) || (wascypos == iscypos)) {
      // if we've just scrolled past the destination, or
      // we haven't moved from the last scroll (i.e., we're at the
      // bottom of the page) then scroll exactly to the link
      window.scrollTo(0,dest);
      // cancel the repeating timer
      clearInterval(ss.INTERVAL);
      // and jump to the link directly so the URL's right
      location.hash = anchor;
    }
  },

  getCurrentYPos: function() {
    if (document.body && document.body.scrollTop)
      return document.body.scrollTop;
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
      return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (window.pageYOffset)
      return window.pageYOffset;
    return 0;
  },

  addEvent: function(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    // addEvent and removeEvent
    // cross-browser event handling for IE5+,  NS6 and Mozilla
    // By Scott Andrew
    if (elm.addEventListener){
      elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
      return true;
    } else if (elm.attachEvent){
      var r = elm.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn);
      return r;
    } else {
      alert("Handler could not be removed");
    }
  } 
}

ss.STEPS = 25;

ss.addEvent(window,"load",ss.fixAllLinks);
```

Note: I've tried replacing the 'get by tag' line with: "`var allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('mainnav')`;

An example of the corresponding mark ups is;

```
<li class='mainnav'><a style="margin-left:3px;" href="#topReception" onMouseOver = "if (document.images) document.top.src= 'http://soniahsieh.com/dev/_images/top-hover.png';" onMouseOut = "if (document.images) document.top.src= 'http://soniahsieh.com/dev/_images/top.png';"><img src="/dev/_images/top.png" name="top" border=0></a></li>
```

BUT, the script dies with this change. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE, trying jQuery.**

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $("a.mainnav").each(function() {   // go through all links
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.match(/^#/)) {   // if href starts with #
        $(this).click(function() {  // add a click event to it
            var name = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);  // get the anchor link

            // on click, scroll to the a with a name attribute matching the anchor
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("a[name='" + name + "']").offset().top }, 1000);  
        });
    }
});

    </script>
```

**Corresponding;**

```
<li class='mainnav'><a style="margin-left:3px;" name="topReception" href="#topReception" onMouseOver = "if (document.images) document.top.src= 'http://soniahsieh.com/dev/_images/top-hover.png';" onMouseOut = "if (document.images) document.top.src= '/dev/_images/top.png';"><img src="coolimage/top.png" border=0></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Javascript libraries are sometimes overkill, but you could do this much easier using jQuery and avoid having to deal with all the cross-browser issues yourself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$("a").each(function() {   // go through all links
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.match(/^#/)) {   // if href starts with #
        $(this).click(function() {  // add a click event to it
            var name = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);  // get the anchor link 

            // on click, scroll to the a with a name attribute matching the anchor
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("a[name='" + name + "']").offset().top }, 1000);  
        });
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to go through all links, I want to define a class for this effect.

Comment: Ah ok, well you can change the first bit to:  $("a.className").each(....   to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still isnt working. I've updated the question with where I tried it and the corresponding mark-up. Why is it failing?

Comment: @cam77 , here's a working example on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aKzTK/ . The jquery code has to be put in the document ready section, sorry I missed that out - I've edited it into my answer now.

Comment: Thanks but am trying to use it with a menu defining a couple anchor points.